I can't connect to a database with Fastapi
I am making a project with fastapi and I get the error below when I run the project. I use PostgreSQL for database.
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.asyncpg.ProgrammingError) <class 'asyncpg.exceptions.InvalidForeignKeyError'>: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "fakulte"
[SQL: 
CREATE TABLE bolum (
    adi VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    adres VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    telefon VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    fakulte_id UUID NOT NULL, 
    id UUID NOT NULL, 
    olusturma_zamani TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL, 
    guncelleme_zamani TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id, olusturma_zamani, guncelleme_zamani), 
    FOREIGN KEY(fakulte_id) REFERENCES fakulte (id)
)

]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/f405)

I deleted and restored the database but it still doesn't work

Sounds like the table "fakulte" doesn't exist, or the column referenced doesn't exist so it  can't create the foreign key. Need more info about how you're running this

The table "fakulte" doesn't have a primary key or unique constraint. You have to fix that before you can create a new table that uses a foreign key constraint pointing to this table.
